# Does the svn 1.7 working copy format store the entire history of the repo?

Tags: svn

I'm curious about the capabilities of the new working copy format in Subversion 1.7 (the single .svn directory at the root).

Does it store an entire history of the repo, like git does? Or are the files in pristine merely a copy of the current (unedited) revision from the server? Does svn support working disconnected at all - committing multiple times locally before pushing to the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subversion only maintains the revision you currently have checked out locally.  (Some meta data about other revisions might be cached depending on your client, but the actual file content from other revisions will not be stored.)

There's no way to commit other than committing to the actual repository.  Just a design difference of git vs subversion (centralized vs distributed).

Answer (score 3):

No, the .svn directory keeps a pristine version of what you've checked out of the repository.  (i.e. the BASE revision)  It does not keep all the history.

SVN does not work disconnected.  You need to have a connection to the server, unless of course you've checked out your working copy from a URL like `file:///c:/my_dir` -- which is to say you're working with a local repository.

Comment: To clarify - Subversion does not require a *persistent* connection to the repository. You can make changes to your working copy without a connection to the repository (unless a lock is required), including editing properties, adding & removing files. Only when you need to make a change to the repository itself (commit, lock) or get the latest logs or revisions do you need a connection to the repository.